# Statistical significance of 3 sample point

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, model

I have a data source with an accuracy of 69.3% (when compared with ground truth data). When a model is applied with 3 different parameters the resulting accuracies are 73.088, 74.912 and 72.89. How can I say that the model resulted in significant accuracy improvement over the single data?

Comment: Essentially same question as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/527113/non-parametric-test-of-significance).  Same clarifications needed here as there. Please edit Question. If this is a class assignment, please use `self-study` tag.

Comment: Of the two nearly-duplicate questions, I am answering this one (a) because you asked first and (b) because you correctly proposed (via topic tag) use of a chi-squared test. // However, please edit your question to show the true number of 'subjects' for each of the four percentages you give in your Question. Then if you have follow-up questions one of us can answer in terms of the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be answered without knowing the actual counts.
***Hypothetically,*** if you had 693, 731, 749, and 720 successes (under four
different respective conditions) out of 1000 trials.
then you would have the contingency table `TBL` below.
[Please understand that 1000 is *just a guess* to be able to
illustrate how to run the test in R. You need to use the actual
counts for a proper analysis of your data.]

```
x = c(693, 731, 749, 720)
y = 1000 - x
TBL = rbind(x, y);  TBL
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
x  693  731  749  720
y  307  269  251  280
```

Then a chi-squared test of homogeneity rejects the null hypothesis
that successes are uniformly distributed across the four categories; rejection is
at the 5% level.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 8.2372, df = 3, p-value = 0.04136
```

Looking at a table of the Pearson residuals, it seems
the the greatest relative discrepancies are between
column 1 and columns 2 and 3.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$resi
       [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
x -1.124815  0.2881758  0.9574873 -0.1208479
y  1.818367 -0.4658626 -1.5478662  0.1953618
```

Even though the main hypothesis is barely significant at the 5%
level, ad hoc tests comparing columns 1 & 2 and 1 & 3 might be
appropriate without undue risk of false discovery. (Especially, so if true counts
are much larger than my guess of 1000.)

Comparison of
1 & 3 is significant at the 1% level:

```
chisq.test(TBL[,c(1,3)], cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL[, c(1, 3)]
X-squared = 7.7948, df = 1, p-value = 0.00524
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the question 
If a system/machine runs an accuracy of 69.3%. I have introduced an improvement and the system now runs on accuracy of 73.088, 74.912 and 72.89. So I want to see if the improvement was significantly effective. 

In that case, we have three sample size. Wouldn't our reference value will always be 69.3% to compare with the new three values?

Comment: Suppose you take 69.3 as a standard. Then by a process you don't understand or won't reveal you somehow get three other values you believe to be comparable and all three are above 69,3.  You have no basis to claim the three observations are normally distributed. So you'd have to use a nonparametric test (as suggested in the parallel post). Problem is three is too few observations for a nonparametric test to find significance at 5% level. P-value of one-sided test couldn't be below $1/8.$ // Let me say again percentages without knowing base count are essentially worthless. Glad this is closed.